# ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID returns NULL

Tags: ios, null, contacts

In myapp i pick phone number from contacts.
I need to store the record id and then retrieve the recordref.
To test the logic i tried the following sample 
In the following delegate i take the record id of the person.
Then try to retrieve the Recordref.
The recorder (gref) is null
Please let me know what i am doing wrong.
I have tested this on iPhone 6 with os 8.2

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

     ABRecordID sid = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);

     ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

     ABRecordRef gref = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, sid);

     NSLog(@“org record ref %@",person);

     NSLog(@“new record ref %@",gref);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before using the address book we need to get the permission granted to access the address book. 
example

```
CFErrorRef myError = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef myAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &myError);

__block ABRecordRef gref;

ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(myAddressBook,
                                         ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                    if (granted) {

                        gref = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(myAddressBook, sid);
                        NSString *contactName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(gref));

                        NSLog(@"after record ref %@",gref);
                        NSLog(@"human name %@",contactName);

                    } else {

                        // Handle the case of being denied access and/or the error.

                    }

                                             CFRelease(myAddressBook);

            });
```